# How to pass a variable value from computed to template in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a json response, where in 'products' I have 'funds' and inside funds I have a date field. i want to view the date in template.

I have used forEach for iterating the products and then iterated the funds, then assigned the date to a variable. This is done inside the computed().

Now i want the date to be fetched in the template. But I am not able to fetch it.

I have tried adding the same in methods(), but no success

```
data: function(){
    return {
        date: ''
    }
},


computed: {
        products: function(){
            let products = this.sortedSchemeData.products;
            var year = this.selectedSchemeYear;

            products.forEach(function(product){

            product.funds.forEach(function(fund){
                   var date = fund.fundsProcessDate;
               console.log(date); //some date from json

                })
            });

            return products;
        }
    },


<template>
<div>
<p>date: <b>{{date}}</b></p>
</template>

date: date in json
```

Comment: There is no single `date`. You have an array of `product` objects, and each one has its own `fundsProcessDate`. How is that supposed to be computed into a single date?

Comment: the fundsProcessDate has the same value across all the fund objects. So , if I have to pick the latest one, can I not do it by this way?

Comment: If it's the same, just do `{{ products[0].fundsProcessDate }}`.

Comment: @ChrisG , Right now I am receiving multiple date  value , though the values are same . What will be the best wat to display the date, without changing the json structure?

Comment: Why are you receiving multiple dates? `products[0].fundsProcessDate` should be a single date, no?

Comment: @ChrisG, i tried using {{ products[0].fundsProcessDate }}, but i am not able to see the date on the web page.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: products: [,…]
0: {productCategory: "Executive Pension Plan (EPP)", productName: "Executive Pension Plan (Series A)",…}
charges: ["No", "Varies from 95% to 105% depending on expired duration - which depends on contract term.", "5%",…]
funds: [{fundName: "WPSF", isClosed: false, closureDate: "", isDefault: false,…}]
0: {fundName: "WPSF", isClosed: false, closureDate: "", isDefault: false,…}
amcDetails: [{annualManagementCharge: "0.185", amcFromDate: "01 Jan 1900", amcToDate: "Present"}]
closureDate: ""
fundName: "WPSF"
fundsProcessDate: "11 May 2019"

Comment: here inside products array we have funds and inside the funds we have the processed date.

Comment: Right, it's `{{ products[0].funds[0].fundsProcessDate }}` then.

Comment: hey @ChrisG, it is working fine now.. but few of the json may not contain this field, for that I am getting the error in console `annot read property 'fundsProcessDate' of undefined` . any way to not bring up that in console?

Comment: compute `date` using `this.products.filter(p => p.funds && p.funds.length)[0].funds[0].fundsProcessDate;`

Comment: So you are saying to rewrite the code in the below format:
`computed: {
        products: function(){
            let products = this.sortedSchemeData.products;
            var year = this.selectedSchemeYear;

            products.forEach(function(product){

            product.funds.forEach(function(fund){
                   var date = this.products.filter(p => p.funds && p.funds.length)[0].funds[0].fundsProcessDate;;
               console.log(date); //some date from json

                })
            });

            return products;
        }
    },`

Answer (score 0):

The `products[0].funds[0].fundProcessDate` doesn't handle the case when the first `product` is empty. My [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pm9wlq2w80) below does handle it.

```
computed: {
    date() {
      const found = this.products.find(product =>
        product.funds.some(fund => fund.fundsProcessDate != null)
      );
      return (found && found.funds[0].fundsProcessDate) || "01-01-2019"; //default date if not found from all of them
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Computed-Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) for this scenario.

```
data: function(){
    return {
        date: ''
    }
},
    
computed: {
        products: {
        // setter
          set: function (newValue) {
            let products = newValue;
            var year = this.selectedSchemeYear;

            products.forEach(function(product){
              product.funds.forEach(function(fund){
                   this.date = fund.fundsProcessDate;
                })
              });
            }
          }
        },

<template>
<div>
<p>date: <b>{{date}}</b></p>
</template>
```

Comment: How would i use that in the template? if you could please throw some light on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the same template used in question.